# Disable 'next' button on the component page when there are no selected components

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm using NSIS 2.46 to create a installer for my windows application, I have a component page with 12 checkboxes, that is 12 sections in my NSIS code, now I want to disable the 'Next' button if none of the sections are checked by the user, I'm using this code:
[image: NSIS Code]

Somehow it doesn't accept R registers above R9...

```
    SectionGetFlags ${section11} $R10 
    SectionGetFlags ${section12} $R11
```

The compiler error I'm getting is 
[image: Compiler error]

Please tell me how to disable the 'Next' button if there are more than 10 components...

Comment: Comparing the section flags against 0 is unsafe, you should use the SectionFlagIsSet helper macro in sections.nsh

Comment: Why did you paste images of code? Stackoverflow supports code blocks, click the red question mark in the editor toolbar for help or see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Ok, i didnt know about it..thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic NSIS registers are $0...$9 and $R0...$R9, so you should use $1 and $2 for the last two sections. Or you can create more variables if you want; `Var /GLOBAL R10`.

If section1 to section12 are numbered without gaps you can use a loop:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh

Section A S_1
SectionEnd
Section /o B S_2
SectionEnd
Section C S_3
SectionEnd


Function .onSelChange
StrCpy $0 0
StrCpy $1 ${S_1}
${DoWhile} $1 <= ${S_3}
    ${If} ${SectionIsSelected} $1
        StrCpy $0 1
        ${ExitDo}
    ${EndIf}
    IntOp $1 $1 + 1
${Loop}
GetDlgItem $1 $HwndParent 1
EnableWindow $1 $0
FunctionEnd
```